# Who is following me on Facebook

Tags: facebook, followers

My information is showing that I have two followers but it only lists one. How can I find out who the other follower is?

Answer (score 2):

It happens sometimes on Facebook, e.g. you have 4 likes but you can see only 2-3 only.

There are main 2 reason:

1. Privacy restrictions
2. Due to Deactivation

Now in your case the reason is that, someone followed you and later on **deactivated (not deleted)** his/her account. So his/her reference is added there, the count is incremented and since he/she deactivated his account, the account will not be visible to you.